# Changing material UI button text based on a condition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, button, material-ui

I am using the material UI button for my component and want to change the button text based on a condition that if order amount is 0, show button text as "cancel" else show "refund". Please help me how can I do the same.

```
      <Button
        className={classes.refundButton}
        onClick={() => setIsDialogOpen(true)}
      >
        Refund
      </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator for solution.

```
<Button
  className={classes.refundButton}
  onClick={() => setIsDialogOpen(true)}
  >
    {amount === 0 ? 'Cancel' : 'Refund'}
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This is a different component in which the refund button is there and I have 1 more different component(file) for displaying order summary which has total amount etc. I need to check if the total amount of order is 0 then show cancel text on button else refund. How can I use that by import and export?

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the state and read from there conditionally...

```
import { useState } from "react"


const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0)

<Button
  className={classes.refundButton}
  onClick={() => setIsDialogOpen(true)}
>
  {amount === 0 ? 'Cancel' : 'Refund'}
</Button>
```

Comment: The amount is coming from the backend API in this case.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned but the text says Cancel for both the conditions.

Comment: Can you reproduce this case in codesandbox @AshutoshMishra

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-euclid-ob7b8r?file=/src/App.js

Comment: check this out.